# Why do most countries have so many members of parliament?

Tags: parliament

The US House of Representatives consists of 435 members; the UK parliament has 650 members; the Bangladesh Jatiya Sangsad has 300 members, etc.

Why so many people? Anyone who's, e.g., tried to arrange a place & time for a gathering knows that the more people there are involved, the harder it is to make a decision. It's not just harder to get people to agree, it's also more time-consuming. Further, with 300+ members of parliament, if every one of them were given a chance to speak, even if they only spoke for five minutes, it would still take >1500 minutes (= 25 hours!) to complete. It seems much more logical to have, say, 10 people in parliament.

- Why do most countries have so many MPs? Hundreds seems to be the norm.
- Are there any examples of countries that used to have hundreds of MPs, but have drastically reduced the number of MPs to the tens?

Comment: could be just my projected psychology, but "10", rather than *tens*, sounds much more like *the government* than *my representative*, i.e. at some point such a small committee is unconvincing as representing a region/district, distinct from the government, which is what parliament members are supposed to be doing for their constituents.

Comment: Making it more difficult, and slower, to get things done in a legislature is often regarded as a *feature*, not a bug. Legislation can have a major impact on people's lives, so it's generally worth taking some time over it.

Comment: The voting decisions  are just a matter of democratic majority maths. The decision making process is democratic. The process of formulating the new laws can be flexible as long as a democratic process accepts or rebuffs the laws.

Comment: Representatives are not expected (well, in countries that I am aware of) to speak on every discussed issue. Most of them are present just to vote.

Comment: I don't see any reason not to include Senators here, bringing the US number to 535, and to be technically correct the UK House of Commons has 650, and the UK Parliament 1,443.

Comment: @Steve Melnikoff : Like anything, I'd say this only applies so far, and one can argue that many existing governments are _too slow_ to act on important issues, though I think this has more to do with other things than the number of people sitting on the Legislature.

Comment: It may be a bit curt, but I feel like the simplest answer to this question is simply "It is much easier to secretly bribe/blackmail 5 people than 500".  More representatives makes for a more robust system.

Comment: foremost - the difficulty of arranging meetings is way lower if you consider that said meetings are the main task of parliamentarians

Comment: plain corruption .. they hire brothers, sisters, wifes and husbands, daughters and sons and bam you get on the said number of 100+ ... it's all about money

Comment: I'd ask why so *few*: in the US, the House was capped at 435 members in 1911, when the population was ~92 million. The estimated population is now ~330 million, Each member represents roughly (depending on the state) between 530,000 and 995,000 people. There are countries who, at that level of representation, would have single-member parliaments. Iceland, to pick an example, has one representative per ~5700 people.

Comment: @SteveMelnikoff Indeed; gov't is often bad enough at it's current pace. I'd hate to see how bad things get if they followed the programming mantra "move fast and break things"...

Comment: @chepner: it would be tempting to explain that away by pointing out that the US is a federal republic, with elected state legislatures dealing with more local issues. However, that's true in Germany too, which currently has one of the largest legislative chambers in the world; the same is more-or-less true of the European Parliament as well. In other words: there's no simple answer. :-)

Answer (score 54, accepted):

The intention behind any parliamentary structure is to provide accurate representation of the citizenry as a whole. The general (historical) implementation is to divide the nation up into districts, wards, parishes, or the like, and allow each district to have a voice in the parliament. It is assumed that districts — if they are well-designed, and sufficiently small — will accurately reflect local concerns and interests, so that these local concerns and interests will be heard in parliament through the representative. There is a playoff between the efficacy of representation and the efficacy of parliament as a whole: the smaller the number of constituents in a district, the better the representation, but the greater the number of members of parliament (with all the problems that entails). But however one balances that, nations with large populations are forced to have large parliamentary bodies to have any hope of proper representation at all.

Of course, there are other considerations. For instance, the US Senate is a parliamentary body, but it is meant to represent the interest of US *States*, opposed to the interests of US *citizens*, and so has a smaller number of representatives. Political tactics like gerrymandering and voter suppression can can expand the influence of some groups while diminishing the power of others, destroying the representativeness of the parliamentary body. Some systems try to balance out inequities and unfairnesses by adding extra members to represent minority parties or positions (e.g., proportional representation). There are a lot of different tricks and nuances in systems around the world, but as a general rule any effort to make a system *more* representative of the citizenry is going to increase the number of members of parliament.

It's an old saw in political science that if one wants a *just* society one has to surrender to having an *inefficient* society. Autocrats and dictators are efficient, but that's not always a compliment; Hitler made the trains run on time, but then he used those trains to commit world war and genocide. Representative democracy is slow, contentious, and aggravating — a constant "two steps forward and one step back" affair — but in the long run it grinds its way through to reasonable, moral outcomes. Ten people might be an *efficient*-sized group to rule a nation, but it is pragmatically and statistically impossible to select a group of ten people who are representative of the nation's population as a whole, so their decisions will not reflect the interests of their populace.

Comment: This is the best answer.  It gets to the heart of how the size of parliaments reflects their mission.

Comment: This is a great answer.  Another advantage to a larger corpus of representatives is that it makes it harder to "whip", ie to make conform to the party line, and that means when trying to convince parliament as a whole to vote the way you want them to, you must make appeals to reason and morality, rather than pure partisanship, and this (in theory at least) makes for better decision-making.

Comment: As a note on the US Senate: it was originally formed to represent the interests of the states themselves, with the Senators being appointed by each state's government.  Once the Senators became elected positions through popular vote, it removed any direct input by the states to the federal government.

Comment: @MichaelRichardson: I don't think that's *quite* true. Since senators are elected by the entirety of the populace of a state, that makes them (perhaps) the best representative for the interests of the state (thought of as the aggregate of its population). If senator is merely appointed by the state government, he more closely represents the interests of the people who appoint him in the state government, not of the state itself. I know there's a tendency to treat incorporated bodies as fictional individuals in the modern world, but that's a fiction we should all be wary of.

Comment: @TedWrigley Slightly modify my statement to "Once the Senators became elected positions through popular vote, it removed any direct input from the state governments to the federal government".

Comment: This answer has a major flaw, in that in most places it's not possible to get into parliament with a single member. A party has to clear some electoral threshold. If there are 300 members, of parliament, but the smallest possible party has to achieve 5 seats, it might as well just have 60 members.

Comment: @blues: Which system does this? here in the US it's perfectly possible to get one or two independent or third-party representatives in at the state or federal level; I don't know which system sets this kind of threshold.

Comment: @TedWrigley: Germany, Brazil, Austria, Turkey, Norway, Poland, Sweden, Isreal ... Wikipedia has a list and it's rather long

Comment: @blues Strike Germany from that list. While a party list needs to gain 5 % of the vote share, an individual *candidate* need only get a majority in their constituency. Independent candidates have run and are running all the time although they don’t tend to be successful. On the other hand, in 1998 two candidates of the then-PDS were directly elected in their districts even though the party as a whole failed to clear the 5 % threshold nationwide. (Had a third candidate been elected in a third district, the PDS would have joined parliament anyway, see *Grundmandatsklausel*.)

Comment: the pds is the perfect example why Gernany should be on that list. in 2002, despite the Grundmandat and having 4,4% of the vote, which would be proportional to about 26 seats at the time, they only got 2.

Comment: "Hitler made the trains run on time..." Hitler and the Nazis were not as efficient as most people think. https://coffeecuphistory.wordpress.com/2013/05/06/the-myth-of-nazi-efficiency/

Answer (score 59):

## Subcommittees

The real work isn't done in plenary session. It isn't even done in the subcommittees. It is done *preparing for* the subcommittees.

One of the key tasks of most parliaments is to decide on taxes and a budget. That's thousands of pages, which should be **understood** line by line by someone. But nobody can understand the details of the science budget, *and* the defense budget, *and* the health budget, *and* corporate taxes, and so on.

So the agriculture subcommittee prepares a slice of the budget and submits it to the budget subcommittee, etc.

To make that work, each subcommittee must be staffed by a representative section of the parliament and each representative can only be in a few subcommittees.

Comment: this is regional, not all countries work like that.

Comment: @jwentig While the example maybe regional the general idea is about right. Representatives do much more work than casting a vote from time to time. If you had a parliament of 20 members you'd actually end with about the same 300 people, only they wouldn't be elected but hired.

Comment: @Rekesoft **"Representatives do much more work than casting a vote from time to time."** I think 50% of public disillusionment with politics comes from citizens not understanding this. (the other 50% is corruption)

Comment: @xLeitix I think the disillusionment with politics comes from politicians not understanding this and simply voting as they're told by their party leadership rather than thinking for themselves.

Comment: @jwenting which likely won't change 'til there's law giving each candidate a set amount of federal/state campaign $ and it's not allowed to spend more than that on things like ads for/against people, etc. -- people do what the leadership says otherwise the leadership will get them primaried/etc.

Answer (score 39):

A parliament with a dozen or so members is a cabinet. You're effectively deleting the parliament completely and going with a government that consists of a single body: the cabinet, without any checks and balances introduced by parliamentary oversight.

It also (as mentioned already) removes any idea of influence over policy making that less populated regions of the country may have had when they had representatives in said parliament, as they're now completely without representation, as the only votes that matter are those in the most populated parts of the country (usually a few large cities).

That situation creates a lot of resentment in rural areas, and can well lead to rebellion.

Comment: When did OP suggest deleting the parliament?

Comment: @Blueriver They didn't, but it's the logical consequence of having very few members.

Comment: @JSLavertu no, the logical consequence is that you have a second body that is the same size of the cabinet (unless by "very few" you mean "exactly zero").

Comment: @Blueriver I don't mean *literally* deleting the parliament. It's just that the checks and balances that come with a parliament pretty much require a large number of members. It's not too hard to convince a handful of people to follow some "bad" idea, but much harder to convince several dozens. In a system where there's only 10 members, 5 people represents half the power, but if you have 500 members, it's only 1%. The amount of people a bad actor needs to influence is MUCH higher than can done effectively (and secretly).

Comment: yes, exactly what I meant, better said.

Comment: Why would a parliament with only 10 members mean that less populated regions of the country have no representatives? For example, to shrink the UK parliament down to 10 people, the simplest way would be to divide the country into ten pieces each with the same amount of population, and have each piece elect one representative.

Comment: @Allure because the regions with the highest population density are going to get the most seats. Taking your idea to the Netherlands for example, Amsterdam would get 2 seats, Rotterdam, the Hague, and Utrecht would get 1 seat each, while combined the provinces of Flevoland and Drenthe would get only a single seat. This is precisely what the dual chamber nature of the US congress is designed to prevent, as well as their electoral college.

Comment: @jwenting well yes, but the provinces of Flevoland and Drenthe would still have representation in the parliament. I'm not following the logic in the 2nd paragraph of the answer, which says "less populated regions of the country ... [are] now completely without representation", and also "the only votes that matter are those in the most populated parts of the country". In the arrangement above, every vote is worth just as much as every other vote.

Comment: @Allure why would one of the MPs focus on the needs of those in the unpopulated areas if it makes no difference to their future? The number of the people in the urban areas would easily outvote those in the rural areas.

Comment: @Tim how would that change with more members of parliament? Sure, with more members of parliament you could have some of them represent underpopulated areas, but you could do that with 10 people too.

Comment: @Allure in that case you’ve either got one MP for a huge land area, with diverse needs (hint: Scotland and Wales are both sparsely populated, but have very different views, voting trends, language, etc) or you have a mixture of urban and rural in one constituency, which causes a focus on the urban.

Answer (score 16):

"Why so many people?"

Is it many?
For two of the examples you give (Bangladesh and the US), it is around 600 000 inhabitants per seat.

Even the smallest of micro states still manage to put 7 people in the houses.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_legislatures_by_number_of_members

Comment: Indeed.  If we used the historical precedent of 35,000 citizens per seat, we would have an enormous Congress, and possibly better gov't.

Comment: @LawnmowerMan Or multiple governments. Just sayin' :P

Answer (score 7):

One of the reasons is to be able to divide the votes, The Netherlands for example is horribly fractured. It currently has 15 parties and during the election there were 28 competing.

If your idea of a 10 man parliament would come in then less then half of the current parties would be part of the parliament. With about 1/3 of the votes disappearing in the trash can. Besides that people often want somebody from their own area to be part of the parliament. If in the Netherlands all parliament members were native South-Holland and none from the other 11 provinces you will start having issues with proper representation. This is because even in a country as small as mine the differences are massive between the provinces.

Another idea of this "by the numbers" approach is that the more members parliament has the less chance there is of them all being corrupted/bribed. That's why you will mostly see parliaments in the 10's in nations where the corruption is high (or where the population is low).

> Further, with 300+ members of parliament, if every one of them were given a chance to speak, even if they only spoke for five minutes, it would still take >1500 minutes (= 25 hours!) to complete.

Most people usually don't even speak in the parliament, they are just there to vote while a more silver-tongued member of the party speaks on behalf of its entire party. When it comes to part

***Edit: The Following concerns info about the comment Itamar Mushkin made.***

The Netherlands has 150 seats so a government has to be formed by a coalition of parties having a total of 76+ seats. The current polls have the following outcome:

- VVD 20
- PVV 19
- PvdA 18
- FvD 16
- CDA 14
- D66 13
- Gl 12
- SP 9
- 50+ 9
- PvdD 6
- CU 6
- SGP4
- DENK 3

So the 4 largest parties and 1 other random party is needed to form the coalition, now here are the problems.

- PVV and FvD don't want to form a coalition with the VVD due to them
  being pro-EU and having made budget cuts on healthcare. (Also some bad history there)
- PvdA, D66, GL and PvdD don't want to form a coalition with PVV or FvD
  because they are considering them "Right wing Extremists". And they are also not keen on forming one with the VVD.

  - SGP only finds support from CU and CDA due to them being conservative Christians.
  - And Nobody wants to work with DENK because they can barely be called a Dutch party due to them openly supporting foreign governments over the Dutch one.

So the most realistic possibility would be VVD, PvdA, CDA, D66 and GL but we already currently have such a government and it is failing. (Massive protests and an approval rating in the low 30's)

Namely a broad coalition, with our current one being VVD, CDA, CU and D66 who had 76 seats together but according to current polls only have 53 (almost a 1/3 loss). This is because they had to make concessions due to their differences.

A few examples:

- D66 supports euthanasia, CU and CDA are Christian parties that see
  that as suicide (and therefor a sin).
- D66 wants to take in more refugees and pay more towards the EU, VVD which is an economic party wants the opposite.
- D66 is more open to Islam while the other 3 are not.

And the list goes on like this for a while, and you could say that D66 is the problem here (which is true) but the point is that the other parties weren't large enough, have bad blood with the VVD or are even more left wing then the D66.

Until a coalition is formed our government works chaotic and can even lead to new elections with probably similar results.

And on a side note, VVD is called a party killer. Every party that ever formed a coalition with them had massive losses the next election. This is because VVD (although they are declining rapidly now) has been one of the biggest the last few elections forcing it's coalition partners to make decisions that are unpopular with their voters.

Comment: @ItamarMushkin to summarise: the seat distribution distribution combined with fundamental differences in ideology between the largest parties makes it next to impossible to create a stable coalition government.

Comment: The problem with the VVD is even bigger. The other parties have also forced the VVD to take unpopular decisions, and even repeatedly so (as the VVD has been in power so long). VVD voters generally expect the VVD leaders to give in to the EU demands, again. That's why the VVD is not gaining from the losses of other parties.

Comment: @ItamarMushkin: A widely shared opinion is that many of those parties don't **want** to rule. PVV, FvD, GL, SP, 50+, PvdD and DENK are generally considered to be such parties, based on their observed behavior. (GL is an edge case, they dropped out of negotiations last time). As the answer shows, these poll at 74 seats combined. That only leaves you with 76 seats for parties that want to rule, just not with each other. With a 150 seats total, 76 is the absolute minimum so with the current polls it is impossible to form a majority government.

Comment: This is not the reason. Netherlands is unique in its extremely low threshold (0.67%).  Most parliamentary systems have thresholds of perhaps 4%, 5%, or even 10%.  Small parties are kept out on purpose, but the total number of seats is still large, much larger than The Netherlands in fact, which has one of the smallest parliaments in Europe, and also for that reason irrelevant to answer this question. You've also added a lot of debatable and irrelevant analysis here.

Comment: @gerrit just checking the numbers, almost every party in the list (except DENK and SGP) got 6 seats (4%) or above - so even a 4% threshold won't change the picture much. and 4% is not low (my country, Israel recently increased it to 3.25% - with bad consequences). and 10% is huge, what country has that?

Comment: @ItamarMushkin Netherlands has 0.67% which *is* low, [Turkey has 10%](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electoral_threshold#Legal_electoral_thresholds_in_various_countries).  At the last elections, 7 parties had more than 4%, 6 parties between 0.67% and 4%, and 15 less than 0.67%. Parliament would still be fractured with a higher threshold; but this answer is wrong because most parliaments are larger AND have higher thresholds. Parliaments are not large to accommodate small parties as usually small parties are kept out by design.

Comment: I agree with your bottom line: Parliaments are not large to accommodate small parties, as usually small parties are kept out by design, regardless of whether they are at fault for fracturing and inability to form coalitions.

Comment: The Netherlands is also an exception in the sense that MP's for the tweede kamer (the "house") are chosen directly and do not represent a district. Senators are a different story which is way too long for a comment, but that still boils down to: Yes.. but no.

Comment: Fracturing is usually caused by the voting system and not the number of seats. USA, UK have more seats and one party in control. Culture is another factor.

Answer (score 5):

Sometimes parliaments grow over time. Here in Germany, the parliament ("Bundestag") is supposed to have 598 members (for ~80 million people). However, we have a special voting system where some MPs are elected as direct candidates in each district by a majority vote ("first vote") but the overall composition of the parliament is determined by a proportional representation of the second vote, adding another batch of MPs.

This systems gives a lot more directly elected to the big parties than they would receive according to the second vote. These seats are called [overhang seats](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overhang_seat). This alone already gives some additional seats in the parliament. However, some years ago it was ruled that is is not legal to have an overhang. Rather than reforming the voting system such that an overhang can no longer occur, the parliament voted for job-securing[A] full compensation of overhang seats to the other parties, resulting in a total of 709 seats in the current legislation period. With the decreasing importance of bigger parties, this problem is likely to get even worse.

[A] I know this sounds a bit snarky but it is probably a part of the truth why parliaments are growing and rarely shrinking on reforms. There is simply no incentive for the members of a parliament to make a reform that makes a lot of them lose their jobs.

Comment: same reason parliament in the Netherlands rarely votes against the cabinet, as the elections resulting from a vote of no confidence would cause a lot of them to lose their very well paid jobs.

Comment: You could probably say the same of the reduction of the UK parliament from 650 to 600 MPs, which was proposed in 2010 and the ever expanding House of Lords stuffed with ex MPs.

Comment: Fun fact: the norm size of the Bundestag was reduced from 650 to 598 members between the 1998 and the 2002 elections. Second fun fact: the current system of full compensation was born recently after overhang went uncompensated for decades and the Federal Constitutional Court saw the integrity of proportional vote endangered. 2002 certainly still saw fully uncompensated overhang.

Answer (score 4):

### A German perspective

Germany has an unusually large Parliament, with currently 709 members in the Bundestag (lower house), the largest national Parliament chamber in the world.  The number of members is variable due to overhang and leveling seats.  There are 299 electoral districts.  In a district-based first-past-the-post system, that would mean 299 seats, which is not huge for a country like Germany.  But then there are also *at least* another 299 overhang and leveling seats.  Those seats are distributed to make the total number of seats close to proportional, to a total of 598 seats.  But if with 598 seats, there is still insufficient proportionality, they keep adding seats until it is proportional.  The more fractured the election, the larger the number of seats.  Fracturing has been increasing:

- 2002-2005: 603 seats
- 2005-2009: 614 seats
- 2009-2013: 622 seats
- 2013-2017: 631 seats
- 2017-2021: 709 seats

One solution would be to have less districts.  A party that is regionally strong and benefits from many district seats will oppose this.  Another solution is to have less compensation seats.  This disadvantages parties that get a smaller amount of the vote more equally nationally distributed.  A cross-party committee is trying to work out a compromise, for most agree that 709 members is too many.

### A cynical interpretation

Essentially, Parliament decides the size of Parliament.  If Parliament decides to decrease the size of Parliament, members of Parliament are more likely to lose their job.  Therefore, Parliament is unlikely to decide to reduce the size of Parliament.

Comment: "the largest national Parliament chamber in the world": [that's not true](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_legislatures_by_number_of_members). You could, however, say that it's the largest lower house of any democratic country, which rules out the EU (not a country) (751), China (not a democracy) (2980), and the UK House of Lords (not a lower house) (793).

Comment: fracturing is not a sufficent explanation if you notice that it has **constantly** increased.

Comment: @Tom and Gerrit: Nice cherry-picking of the numbers because the norm size went down to 598 from 650 in 2002. Furthermore, the answer does not state that overhang was not compensated until the 2013 election. Finally, it is not correct calling the second set of 299 regular seats ‘overhang and levelling seats’. Overhang seats are only those directly elected candidates that *surpass* what a party should get as a fraction of 598 and levelling seats are only those that level the surpassing overhang seats.

Comment: @Jan I just took the numbers from Wikipedia.  I was not aware it went down in 2002, so the cherry picking was not on purpose on my side.  I admit that the details of overhang and levelling seats are beyond my knowledge.

Comment: Overhang seats are only loosely connected to fracturing. The real driver for overhang seats is the ratio between fraction of the direct (FPTP) mandates to fraction of secondary (proportional) votes among the patries that took the 5 % hurdle. The highest such ratio for any party determines how many seats are needed to keep proportionality.  As soon as that ratio is > 598/299 = 2 for any party, overhang seats are needed to satisfy both proportionality and the direct election results. Currently CSU with a ratio of 2.37 determines the size of the Bundestag (closely followed by CDU with 2.19).

Comment: So even if CDU/CSU were only one party, and all other votes would have gone to SPD, they'd have a ration of 2.23, so there would still be 68 overhang seats (instead of 110 now), and that would also be the number of overhang seats if CDU and CSU were the same party. Fracturing can increase the need for overhang seats, but the type of fracturing that is really likely to do that is the one we see between CDU and CSU: If there are many separate parties that start in disjoint regions, the likelihood to have one really strong party in any region increases. Fracturing in the sense that there are many

Comment: parties that start throughout Germany doesn't have the additional "advantage" that the maximum of n regional ratios determines Bundestag size

Comment: "One solution would be to have less districts. A party that is regionally strong and benefits from many district seats will oppose this." Well, the proportionality with those many overhang seats means that there is no disproportional advantage for such a party. Moreover, I'd think it likely that fewer larger election districts for direct mandates would benefit the party that got most districts already now: small islands of other direct candidates may be "eaten up" that way. So I think the general "parliament deciding how many of them would be out of job" is more relevant.

Comment: @cbeleitessupportsMonica You clearly understand this better than I do!

Answer (score 3):

Members of parliament are also the *representatives* of the population in their constituencies, as a last resort for dealing with their individual problems.

Historically, transportation imposed a practical limit to the size of geographical area which one individual could "represent." With modern communication methods that may no longer apply, but there is still a limit to the workload that "one representative" can handle, since it is likely to involve interaction with government ministers, etc.

A recent high profile example in the UK would be the death of [Harry Dunn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Death_of_Harry_Dunn), allegedly involving a car driven by the wife of a US government employee, but MPs deal with many lower-level issues.

Answer (score 3):

The United States of America is a Federation of States.  Other countries, like the United Kingdom, *aren't*

This means that, for example, the UK Houses of Parliament are roughly analogous to both the US Congress, *and* the individual Legislatures of each State Government.  As such, you are currently ignoring *quite* a lot of people on the USA side of things:

```
              │ Lower House │ Upper House │ Total 
USA Congress  │      435    │      100    │   535 
USA States    │     5411    │     1971    │  7382 
══════════════╪═════════════╪═════════════╪═══════
USA Total     │     5846    │     2071    │  7917 
UK Parliament │      650    │      793    │  1443
```

The population of the UK is about 66 million, and the population of the USA is about 327 million - so the USA has about 5 times the population of the UK, and about 5.5 times the Legislature, to go with about 40 times the landmass.

(Note that due to a quirk of how the UK Parliament formed, it is the only [bicameral government](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bicameralism) in the world where the Upper House has more members than the Lower House)

If you also include the UK Devolved Governments of the Scottish Parliament (129 members), National Assembly for Wales (60 members), and Northern Ireland Assembly (90 members or 0 members, [depending on how much they're arguing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Northern_Ireland_Assembly#Ten_years_of_power-sharing_and_three_years_of_deadlock)) to make it 7917 vs 1722, then this would mean the US Government is only ~4.6 times the size of the UK one

Comment: You probably should include the devolved governments in your table. As the last paragraph suggests they are a better balance with the State governments you've listed for the US. I assume both places have city/county councils so I wouldn't take it down another level.

Comment: The UK House of Lords has recently had its ranks reduced greatly to 75 voting members IIRC.

Answer (score 1):

There are two reasons, both really simple.

The first is that you want to represent all relevant interests in the country, including minorities. Not just political positions - ideally you want someone in parliament who is a single mother, someone who is gay, someone who is a farmer - at least one or a few people from every possible religion, profession, education, etc. etc. -- and you just need lots of people to have a reasonable chance to get a representative distribution.

The second reason is also why #1 doesn't actually work: Career politicians. Not just are most politicians lawyers, teachers or one of a small set of jobs that aren't actually nearly that common in the population, being a politician as a profession also means that all these people need jobs - the larger the parliament, the more politicians have a job. Who makes the rules that govern the size of the parliament? The very politicians who profit from them. If that's not a conflict of interest, I don't know what is.

Some parliaments have a 3rd reason, namely that they are "working parliaments", i.e. they don't just vote, but also work on issues, prepare laws, check on the government, etc. - other parliaments have this work done not by parliamentarians but by their staff. They could get the same work done with fewer politicians and more staff.

Answer (score 1):

Running the entire country and voting for it's administration decisions takes a lot of work, so a lot of employees is efficient, and electing them is representative. Individual parliamentarians are contingent for local issues like trade fairs, shopping centers, water leaks, everything local, which may benefit from national attention and national money, as well as responsible for national legislation.

The votes adhere to democratic mathematics of majority regardless of the number of parliamentarians.

So a parliament can logically employ as many local representatives as would be employed by a large company that runs affairs nationally, for example an insurance company with 500 employees... same attribution of labour, different employment rules.

Answer (score 0):

Not directly an answer to the second bullet point in the OP, but closely related: [Italy votes to slash size of parliament by a third](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-europe-49979103).

Italy voted to reduce the number of MPs in the lower house from 634 to 400, and the number of senators from 315 to 200. The driving reason behind the change to the constitution is apparently money - the move is projected to save [EUR 1 billion in a decade](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-europe-49979103) (according to calculations "an MP costs €230,000 per year and a senator €249,600").

A counterargument pointed out in the article is that reducing the number of MPs weakens democracy and makes political lobbying more effective, so that could be an answer to the title question.